# When you click on the button, display a message

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a checkbox and a button. When you click the button, display the message "Thank you" if the checkbox is clicked. If the checkbox is not active, the message "Goodbye"

```
<input  type="checkbox" id="checkBox">
<input type="button" id='button'>
```

Comment: Hmmmm and what do you want? What's you trouble?

Comment: a simple if else statement with condition ```$('#' + id).is(":checked")``` and an alert should do it ... try doing it yourself ...

Comment: Did you at least try to do yourself?

Comment: Where would you like to display the message?

Comment: Dear Alyasha, you will need to add a script to your html code, inside this script you can access the html components via DOM and perform the action messages you need. In order to help you better please build a entire example containing the javascript and html. If you have no idea what I'm talking about you, I would like to recommend you a javascript training, there is plenty on internet.

Comment: I tried for a long time. Thanks for the advice. And for the help, thanks to you all

Comment: This reads like a homework assignment.

Comment: Almost there is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <input  type="checkbox" id="checkBox">
<input type="button" id='button' value = "Click me" onclick="FbotonOn()">
<p id="texto"></p>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
function FbotonOn() { 

    if(document.getElementById('checkBox').checked)
        document.getElementById('texto').innerHTML = "Thank you";
    else
        document.getElementById('texto').innerHTML = "Good Bye";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("checkBox").addEventListener("click,", function(){ 
console.log("check box click")});


document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click,", function(){ console.log("button click")});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery version

```
$('#button').on("click",function(){

    if( $('#checkBox').is(":checked")){
      alert("checked")
    }else{
      alert("un checked")
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){

 var checkoutHistory = document.getElementById('ChkCheck');
    if (checkoutHistory.checked) {

alert("Ok");
}
else{
alert("Check box not selected");
}
})
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="ChkCheck">
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="btnSubmit">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var checkboxTrue = "CheckBox is checked";
var checkboxFalse = "Please click on the checkbox";

function check() { 

    if(document.getElementById('checkBox').checked) {
        alert(checkboxTrue);
}
    else {
        alert(checkboxFalse);
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> CheckBox </title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox">
<input type="button" id='button' value ="Click me" onclick="check()">
</body>
</html>
```